# Не работает программа для резервного копирования файлов

Tags: python, zip, резервное-копирование

```
import os
import time

source = ['"D:\\Backup_file\\message"']

target_dir = 'D:\\Backup\\Reserve'

today = target_dir + os.sep + time.strftime('%Y%m%d')
now = time.strftime('%H%M%S')

if not os.path.exists(today):
os.mkdir(today)
print('Каталог успешно создан', today)

target = today + os.sep + now + '.zip'

zip_command = "7zFM -qr {0} {1}".format(target, ' '.join(source))

if os.system(zip_command) == 0:
print('Резервная копия успешно создана в', target)
else:
print('Создание резервной копии не удалось!')
```

Вывод:

> Каталог успешно создан D:\Backup\Reserve\20190921
>   Резервная копия успешно создана в D:\Backup\Reserve\20190921\165401.zip

При выполнении программы содается папка, но нет файла для копирования и открывается программа 7Zip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте `7za.exe` для таких целей, можно `7z.exe` из пакета установщика.

```
"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe a -tzip {0} {1}".format(target, ' '.join(source))
```

Это версии архиватора для скриптов и командной строки.

`a` - [команда](https://sevenzip.osdn.jp/chm/cmdline/commands/index.htm) добавить файлы в архив

`-tzip` - [параметр](https://sevenzip.osdn.jp/chm/cmdline/switches/index.htm) тип архива zip, не обязательно если имя файла заканчивается на `.zip`.

Также можно обратить внимание на `7zG.exe` - версия с выводом ошибок и результатов в окошко. `7zFM` - это файловый менеджер для просмотра содержимого архивов.

Comment: Не могли бы вы сказать что делает код 'a' и '-tzip'?

Comment: добавил ссылки на описания параметров