# os.system() не работает, а если команду zip-command скопировать в cmd, то она нормально отрабатывает

Tags: python, windows-7

Изучаю Python по книге "A Byte of Python", немного переделал пример из книги, вместо 'zip' использую '7-zip'. И os.system() не работает, а если команду zip-command скопировать в cmd, то она нормально отрабатывает. Пробовал добавлять в PYTHONPATH путь до 7-zip.exe, всё безуспешно.

```
import os
import time

# 1. Файлы и каталоги, которые необходимо скопировать, собираются в список.
source = ['C:\\Users\user1\Desktop\python_source\lessons_code', '"C:\\Users\user1\Desktop\python_source\my idea"']
# Для имён содержащих пробелы, необходимо использовать двойные кавычки внутри строки

# 2. Резервные копии должны храниться в основном каталоге резерва
target_dir = 'D:\\backup' 

# 3. Файлы помещаются в zip-архив.
# 4. Именем для zip-архива служит текущая дата и время.
target = target_dir + os.sep + time.strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S') + '.zip'

# 5. Используем команду "zip" для помещения файлов в zip-архив.
zip_command = '"C:\\Program Files\\7-Zip\\7z.exe" a -tzip -ssw -mx5 -r0 {0} {1}'.format(target, ' '.join(source))

# Запускаем создание резервной копии
print(zip_command) # отладка: получаем команду и вставляем её в cmd для проверки работоспособности.

if os.system(zip_command) == 0:
    print('\nРезервная копия успешно создана в', target)
else:
    print('\nСоздание резервной копии НЕ УДАЛОСЬ')
```

Comment: Что это за книга такая!.. каждый месяц кто-нибудь сюда приходит с этим неработающим кодом.

Comment: @Эникейщик В итоге, решили проблему этого кода?

Comment: Да кто его знает. Посмотрите этот вопрос, там тоже 7z использовали https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1026878/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%bc%d0%b0-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вероятнее всего проблема - неправильное написание и трактовка литералов строк python. Тема достаточно сложная, но если кратко, то те стоки, которые мы должны писать в файле скрипта не обязательно являются тем, что мы имеем в виду, а также тем что мы видим когда вызываем `print`. Поэтому для отладки приложений лучше не использовать `print`, а так или иначе работать с самими данными. Попробуйте следующий код:

```
import os
import time

source = [r'C:\Users\user1\Desktop\python_source\lessons_code', r'"C:\Users\user1\Desktop\python_source\my idea"']
target_dir = r'D:\backup'
target = target_dir + os.sep + time.strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S') + '.zip'
zip_command = r'""C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a -tzip -ssw -mx5 -r0 {0} {1}"'.format(target, ' '.join(source))

if os.system(zip_command) == 0:
    print('\nРезервная копия успешно создана в', target)
else:
    print('\nСоздание резервной копии НЕ УДАЛОСЬ')
```

Я заменил все литералы строк с двойным `'\\'` на `r'\'`, а также добавил там, где их не было (в строке `source = ...`). Помимо этого, все команды посылаемые в `os.system` лучше **дополнительно** оборачивать в кавчки. Именно это и является причиной такого разного результата в работе `cmd` и `os.system`. Код рабочий, я проверил его только что с использованием своих путей файлов.

Вообще обычно для этих целей используют либо [встроенные возможности](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html), либо более [высокоуровневые инструменты](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html). Вот пример с использованием модуля `subprocess`:

```
import subprocess

# ваш код вычисления zip_command здесь

if subprocess.run([zip_command], shell=True).returncode == 0:
    ...
else:
    ...
```

Переменная окружения [PYTHONPATH](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH) не влияет на системные переменные, а предназначена для добавления дополнительных путей **поиска модулей python**.